# Cannot Instant Run: legacy multi-dex on Dalvik runtime

Tags: android-studio, android-multidex, instant-run

When I ran my app, it said that

> Cannot Instant Run: legacy multi-dex on Dalvik runtime

Does it means that I can't use Instant Run when I use multi-dex?

I'm using Android Studio beta4.

Comment: Read this on the official website : "Apps that are using legacy multi-dex (with minSdkVersion < 21), with a main dex file near the 65K method limit may not build. This would require reworking the app to make room in the main dex list by reducing the number of classes required in the main dex file".

Answer (score 3):

In order to activate multiDex at old android versions you have to set **multiDexEnabled** to *true*, add dependency and extend your application class from **MultiDexApplication** or launch *MultiDex.install(this)* in your application class, which will cause legacy multiDex installation.

However since Intant Run can't work with legacy multiDex you have to use normal one. All you need is removing all that code above except of **multiDexEnabled** flag set to *true*. This method is only supported by devices with **API 21** and above.

Feel free to correct me if something is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps proguard and minification can help you. It seems there is no other way without a new device.

Comment: Btw, instant run works fine on emulators. You can use new google emulator or Genymotion

Comment: My computer has only 8G memory!

Comment: My computer at office also has only 8GB RAM. Genymotion works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation Instant Run is disabled by Android Studio in case multidex is enabled for API level 20 or lower and app is deployed on API level 20 or lower.

[Documentation link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-pre-l)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from your ProjectName/app/build.gradle

`android {
   defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
}`

remove **multiDexEnabled true** and you will able to instant run.

Comment: I need it  to  divide dex.